# Session["variable"] getting overwritten when multiple users logged in

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, session

I'm facing an Issue with `HttpContext.Current.Session["variable"]`. It's getting overwritten when multiple users are logged in my web application at the same time in the same network. And the application is hosted on Windows Azure.

My method to get the logged in user is this:

```cs
public static string GetLoginUser()
{
    Login login = (Login)HttpContext.Current.Session["Login"];
    return login.User;
}
```

When 2 or more users are using the application in different computers and different session one `Session["Login"]` prevail above all the others. But it doesn't go against the `Session["variable"]` scope?

Comment: Why are you storing the logged in user in the session?

Comment: How do you have session state configured ?

Comment: You've only given us half the equation, if that. Can you provide the code that you use that stores the session variable?

Comment: Session variable is not shared between different users so I think you implement something wrong, can you put your session set code including any static variable used.